# Content-Disposition: form-data; name

Tags: php, html, curl

I am wondering how to get the message value from the html result below which is accuired by the code below:

```
$rawPostData = file_get_contents('php://input');
var_dump($rawPostData);
```

HTML result

```
string(366) "------------------------------b8059a4b17b3 Content-Disposition: form-data; name="message" title ------------------------------b8059a4b17b3 Content-Disposition: form-data; name="userid" userid ------------------------------b8059a4b17b3 Content-Disposition: form-data; name="date" January 21, 2013, 1:16 am ------------------------------b8059a4b17b3-- " "
```

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking here.

Comment: How about `apache_response_headers()['Content-Disposition']`?

Answer (score 1):

Solution:

in your curl:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,http_build_query($postarray));
```

in your api script:

```
$rawPostData = file_get_contents('php://input');

parse_str($rawPostData,$rr);
var_dump($rr['message']);
```